# Completion handler for initPublisher

Tags: cordova, opentok

We used to use:
https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/

But now we are updating to officially supported plugin:
https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok

I just notice, songz's version used to have a completion handler for initPublisher method:
[Code here](https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/www/opentok.js#L5)
But surprisingly, it was removed (the third param) in this new version from Opentok labs:
[Code here](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/www/opentok.js#L5)

Just wondering, how can we handle it now? Tokbox documentation shows how it is still available in js SDK
[OT#initPublisher](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Song's original plugin had three parameters for `initPublisher`, but it did not support a completion handler. Instead, the [`initPublisher`](https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/www/opentok.js#L412) function accepted the following parameters:

- `apiKey`
- `domId`
- `properties`

The plugin under the OpenTok Labs organization (built on top of Song's) removed the `apiKey` parameter because it wasn't needed anymore. I've gone ahead and opened an [issue](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/issues/118) on the repo for adding a completion handler to the `initPublisher` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see. I meant https://github.com/IjzerenHein/cordova-plugin-opentok/ instead of songz's, which it does have the completion handler :)
Thanks for your answer Manik